# Star chart using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, proj

Is it possible to configure Openlayers and Proj4js to display a star chart?

I have the right ascension and declination of the stars I want to display, which I could put in a vector layer, but how should I set up the projection?

Comment: You can view Earth from space with OpenLayers and proj4 using an orthographic projection https://codesandbox.io/s/orthographic-kcype  I think it could also be used to show a hemisphere of space as seen from from Earth.

Comment: I can't see how to get this working as an "inside looking out" view.

Also, it is possible to rotate ortho projections?